# Differentiation of Expectation w.r.t distribution

Tags: distributions, variational-bayes

I was looking into Coordinate Ascent Variational Inference formula and came across a step where we need to find the argmax of q($z_j$) for the equation given below. I am not sure how the differentiation of the expected value w.r.t the distribution happens here.

$ \frac{d}{dq(z_j)} [\int q(z_j) E_{q_{-j}}[log(p(z_j|z_{-j}, x))]dz_j] = E_{q_{-j}}[log(p(z_j|z_{-j}, x))]$

Answer (score 0):

I realised that "functionals" was what I was looking for. Also we can use just plain integration rule of $ \frac{d}{dx} \int^b_a f(x,t) dt = \int_a^b  \frac{d f(x,t)}{dx} dt $ where a,b are constants. 
Also $ \frac{d g(x)}{d f(x)} = \frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)} $ using simple chain rule.